# OmniStudio Turbo Extract Preview Error

Tags: vlocity

Doing a Trailhead module - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omnistudio-dataraptors/build-a-dataraptor-turbo-extract-and-dataraptor-load?trail_id=get-to-know-omnistudio

Mapping the Account to equal the AccountId, in Preview using the Key AccountId and the Id as the Value I get the following error on Execute.

```
2022-02-17T09:52:51.017Z: Caught Exception: vlocity_ins.DRQueryService.DRQueryServiceException - Critical Error: Please verify DRMapItems are all correct and notify Vlocity support if this is not related to mapping errors. - Trace: (System Code)
```

Where am I going wrong, please?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/369609/edit) your post and include some screenshots of your DataRaptor setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have occurred as I used the wrong naming convention in creating the DataRaptor.  I had used UpperCamelCase.  Whereas, when I created the same new DataRaptor named in lowerCamelCase, the error did not display.